# How can we stop ListDensityPlot to show results outside data range when using InterpolationOrder -> 0?

Tags: plotting, graphics, data

I have this data

```
b = .1 {{1, 1}, {0, 1}};
pts = Tuples[Range[-20, 20], 2] . b;
data = {#[[1]], #[[2]], Sin[#[[1]] #[[2]]]} & /@ pts;
```

I would like to use `ListDensityPlot` with `InterpolationOrder -> 0`

```
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

There are some data points outside the data range! the date range should be like this

```
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Noteworthy (I think): `ListDensityPlot[data]` is identical to `ListDensityPlot[data,InterpolationOrder -> 1]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Background

Look into [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html).

> `RegionFunction` is an option for plotting functions that specifies the
> region to include in the plot drawn.

If you know how to define the region analytically, that could be faster (Solution 2). Here I first take the more general route of using [`ConvexHullRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullRegion.html)

> `ConvexHullRegion` is also known as convex envelope or convex closure.
> The convex hull mesh is the smallest convex set that includes the
> points $p_i$.

[image]

Region check happens using [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html)

## Solution 1

```
With[
    {reg = ConvexHullRegion[pts]},
    ListDensityPlot[
        data, 
        InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},RegionMember[reg, {x,y}]]
    ] 
]
```

[image]

## Solution 2

Defining the `RegionFunction` by hand

```
ListDensityPlot[
        data, 
        InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x-2 < y  < x + 2]
    ] 
]
```

## Solution 3

See solution by @valarmorghulis, they figured out that pre-defining the [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) makes all the difference and has the best performance. Replicating my version of his solution here for completeness.

```
With[
    {regfunc = RegionMember[ ConvexHullRegion[pts]]},
    ListDensityPlot[
        data, 
        InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
        RegionFunction ->(regfunc[{#1,#2}]&)
    ] 
]
```

## Performance

Using `RegionMember[ ConvexHullRegion[pts], {x,y}]` much slower than `Function[{x, y, z}, x-2 < y  < x + 2]`.

Using [`AbsoluteTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html) I compare the two solutions.

#### Sol 1

[image]

#### Sol 2

[image]

#### Sol 3

[image]

Comment: (+1) and very nicely done. Perhaps you could demonstrate the result from `reg = ConicHullRegion[pts]`

Comment: @bmf `ConicHullRegion` doesn't help here. Does it?

Comment: it is exactly the result from `InterpolationOrder->0`. So yes, you are right. It is not a solution, but I think it's a nice and illustrative connection. This is what I meant.

Comment: I don't understand why `RegionFunction -> Composition[regfunc, Most, List]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

in light of the Answer by @rhermans, the performance can be boosted like the one below, but it would be nice to boost it without using two superimposed graphics and directly obtain using `ListDensityPlot`

```
reg = ConvexHullRegion[pts];
```

then

```
Show[ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0], 
  Graphics[{White, 
    Polygon[{{-4, -4}, {-4, 4}, {4, 4}, {4, -4}} -> 
      reg[[1]]]}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

**Update**

For arbitrarily shaped data, we can predefine the *RegionMember*  and results much faster though don't know why

```
Block[{RegFun = RegionMember[ConvexHullRegion[pts]]}, 
  ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
   RegionFunction -> (RegFun[{#1, #2}] &)]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Adding it in the `RegionFunction` makes it 20 times slow

```
Block[{reg = ConvexHullRegion[pts]}, 
  ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer with similar performance as yours, but you need to define the function by hand.

Comment: That is great, but what if the data are hexagon shaped or other nonunform shape?

Comment: Another interesting question to ask, how to make `RegionMember[ConvexHullRegion[pnts], {x,y}]` fast, or something equivalent.

Comment: @rhermans check my update!

Comment: Nice one! +1 Predefining the function seems like the right way to go.

Comment: Using `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate@RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]]]` achieves the same speedup as predefining the region.