# Abnormal data at the boundary using ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a set of data in the format of `{{long1,lat1,data1},{long2,lat2,data2},.....}`.

Sample file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/hpbzeFiM).

When I plot the data using [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) with the option `InterpolationOrder -> 0`.

```
With[
    {
        data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/hpbzeFiM", "CSV"]
    },
    ListDensityPlot[
        data
        , InterpolationOrder -> 0
        , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
        , PlotLegends -> Automatic
        , PlotRange -> All
        , PlotRangePadding -> 0
        , BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Gray]
    ]
]
```

**The data at the boundary looks abnormal which extends to the edges of the plot.**

May I ask if how can this be fixed?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: see this. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280420/how-can-we-stop-listdensityplot-to-show-results-outside-data-range-when-using-in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we stop ListDensityPlot to show results outside data range when using InterpolationOrder -> 0?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280420/how-can-we-stop-listdensityplot-to-show-results-outside-data-range-when-using-in) It's not only a good idea, but also a requirement that you search for similar questions before posting yours. Duplicates are off-topic. [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). If your question is different, pleas [edit] and explain why and how.

Comment: I have edited your question mainly to move the data to a permanent source that can be seen raw without visiting a website (also fixed some minor formatting).  Normally you can't expect users to jump all the hoops of a download page, and should post data in a way that can be inspected and imported directly. Also think that all questions need to be useful for others in years time, so data links should be permanent.  I did it this time, please try doing it yourself next time.